# WPDB Update using Conditional Arrays

Tags: wpdb

**Issue:** I need to use the update function as per exact same format as below, the issue is with the conditional statement for `id` i.e. [ *WHERE (id = 1 OR id = 2) AND status = true*]

```
$wpdb->update(
    $tbl_request_log,
    array(
        'status'    =>  false,
    ), 
    array(
        'id'        =>  array($req1_id, $req2_id),
        'status'    =>  true,
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not posible with `$wpdb->update()`. If you check the [source code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/#source), you will see these lines (lines 2150 - 2161), there is no way getting an `OR` in there:

```
foreach ( $where as $field => $value ) {
    if ( is_null( $value['value'] ) ) {
        $conditions[] = "`$field` IS NULL";
        continue;
    }

    $conditions[] = "`$field` = " . $value['format'];
    $values[] = $value['value'];
}

$fields = implode( ', ', $fields );
$conditions = implode( ' AND ', $conditions );
```

---

**However**, you can write your own query using [`prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/)

```
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare(
    "UPDATE `$tbl_request_log` SET `status` = false WHERE (`id` = %d OR `id` = %d) AND `status` = true",
    $req1_id,
    $req2_id
));
```